# Changing the desktop wallpaper using C# currently displays tiny image

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a program in C#.net that changes the desktop wallpaper every time that it runs. I have made a program to change the target image and that works perfectly, however when the desktop wallpaper is changed, it only shows a very small image with very large, black borders. Here is the related code:

```
    const int setDesktopWallpaper = 20;
    const int updateIniFile = 0x01;
    const int sendWinIniChange = 0x02;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

    public static void setWallpaper()
    {
        string userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;    // returns COMPUTERNAME\Username
        string[] badUserName = userName.Split('\\');
        string goodUserName = badUserName[1];
        string folderName = @"C:\Users\" + goodUserName + @"\Documents\DesktopPictures";

        string[] images = File.ReadAllLines(folderName + @"\Images.txt");
        string image = images[0];
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(image);

        string fileName = folderName + @"\0" + extension;

        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);

        SystemParametersInfo(setDesktopWallpaper, 0, fileName, updateIniFile | sendWinIniChange);
    }
```

The first three variables are taken from a YouTube tutorial, as are the next two lines. In the setWallpaper class the first 8 lines get the path to the image then the rest is from the tutorial that actually changes the wallpaper.

Basically what I want to know is how to change the desktop wallpaper using C#.net where the image covers the entire desktop background.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: This question is answered, click the check mark to the left of the post that solved your problem to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your registry key to set the style of background to "Stretched".

After this line

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
```

Add

```
key.SetValue("WallpaperStyle", "2");
key.SetValue("TileWallpaper", "0");
```

Comment: thank you so much! That's perfect! I would up vote but I don't have enough reputation. It's exactly what I wanted.